# Problem with get_the_excerpt when using an add_action('the_content') containing script tags

Tags: actions

Because of the add_action I'm doing on get_content(), where I'm appending social media icons to the end of the post, it appears that calls to get_the_excerpt() are picking up the part of the javascript and appending it to the end of the text returned from get_the_excerpt(). I suppose this is caused by the fact that the "" tags are being stripped out (due to the fact get_the_excerpt() filters them out) as a partial answer.

However, why is this being picked up by get_the_excerpt() in the first place?

It results in the text:

> Here is the excerpt.document.write('')...

```
if((get_option('myTest_facebook_like') || get_option('myTest_plus1') || get_option('myTest_tweet')) && !get_option('myTest_share_title')){
    add_action('the_content', 'myTest_get_social', 10);
}


function myTest_get_social($myTest_share = '') {
    global $post;

    if((get_option('myTest_plus1') == '' && get_option('myTest_facebook_like') ==  '' && get_option('myTest_tweet') ==  '') || in_category("dont-show-social", $post ) || get_post_meta($post->ID, '_noShare', true)) return $myTest_share;

    $myTest_share .= '<div class="share" style="margin:10px 0">';

    $myTest_permalink   = is_front_page() ? get_bloginfo('siteurl') : get_permalink();

    if(get_option('myTest_plus1')){
        $myTest_share .='<script type="text/javascript">document.write(\'<div class="g-plusone" href="'.$myTest_permalink.'" data-size="medium" data-count="true"></div>\');</script>';
        global $post;
        if(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_myTest_plus1_href', true)){$myTest_share .= '<script type="text/javascript">function myTest_plus1(){window.location="'.get_post_meta($post->ID, '_myTest_plus1_href', true).'";}</script>';}
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure but you have TAGs in the JS strings. That can cause a lot of issues. Encode the JS string with rawurlencode() and call decodeURIComponent() on this string in JS. Like document.write(decodeURIComponent('<?php echo rawurlencode('<tag>intag</tag>'); ?>'));... See if it helps. And please format your code!

Answer (score 1):

Read [this post](http://digitalnature.eu/blog/2011/09/12/how-to-correctly-hook-your-filter-to-the-post-content/). In your myTest_get_social() function, you need to check if the excerpt filter is active. If it is, just return the content and do nothing else:

```
 if(current_filter() === 'get_the_excerpt')
    return $myTest_share;

 // otherwise, do your stuff
```

Comment: not working current_filter() return only the_content in both

Answer (score 0):

You need to detect when will be filter applicated and skip changes if `get_the_excerpt` filter will be applicated also

```
 public function my_content($content) {
   global $wp_current_filter;
   // filter only post content not excerpt 
   if (in_array('get_the_excerpt', $wp_current_filter)) return $content; 
   return 'post content : ' . $content;
  }
 add_filter('the_content', 'my_content');
```

This issue come when `$post->post_excerpt` (excerpt) is empty. Wordpress try prepare excerpt from $post->content and call the_content filter.